# Is there a way to supply a clean R session for every call to a plumber API in R?

Tags: r, plumber

I have access to a `plumber` API which handles some automatic pipelining workflows for me. However, every job runs on the same R session and I'm a bit concerned regarding different calls interfering with each other.

Off to top of my head the wish is that every call starts on a fresh R session. When regularly programming in R I would just restart the session and have a clean setup but with the `plumber` server this seems to be "not so easy". Some reading also revealed that "cleaning up" your R session without a restart isn't a straight forward thing.

Of course I'm also open to alternative suggestions. Any suggestions and insights are welcome. In the end I would simply like the API calls to return the same thing if the inputs are the same.

Comment: What about   library(RestRserve)?

Comment: do you mean just cleaning the work environment? if so, you could write ```rm(list=ls())``` , but this just cleans your datasets off, so you need to reload whichever dataset you are interested in working in

Comment: Its more about packages than data but generally a vanilla starting point for every call is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think you need to provide an example - with some code - of what exactly persists between calls, and the type of API requests this occurs with, i.e. `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`. Not all requests are required to be idempotent but of those that should be, I'm having difficulty imagining what non-data package-related information is causing an issue.

Comment: Would ‘callr’ be appropriate for you?

Comment: The `callr` library suggestion was very helpful thank you! I'll try and write some sort of code snippet showing how I used it when finished.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments by [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph), `callr` does the job very well.

Doing 1.-3. (see code chunk) several times for different packages will show that every run is performed in a fresh R session (see process_id) and hence that the search paths are independent.

```r
# put this code into the file plumber.R and run:
# plumber::plumb("plumber.R")$run(port=9999)
# 1. click "Try it out"
# 2. enter a package name that you want to try
# 3. click "Execute"

#* @get /search_path
#* @param lib library to load
function(lib) {
  # callr runs the anonymous function in a fresh session 
  rp <- callr::r_bg({
    function(lib) {
      library(package = lib, character.only = TRUE)
      return(list(search_path = search(),
                  process_id = Sys.getpid(),
                  the_time = Sys.time()))
    }
  },
  args = list(lib = lib))
  
  # wait for a result with 30 seconds timeout
  rp$wait(30000)
  if(rp$is_alive() == TRUE) {
    rp$kill()
    stop("time exceeded")
  }
  # return the result
  rp$get_result()
}
```

A bit offtopic but maybe also interesting in this context: Allowing parallel requests can be enabled via the `future` package.

```r
# submit two requests for packages within less than 10 seconds of
# each other and compare the time stamps to see that they were processed
# in parallel and in different sessions

future::plan(future::multisession)

#* @get /search_path
#* @param lib library to load
function(lib) {
  future::future({
    # callr runs the anonymous function in a fresh session 
    rp <- callr::r_bg({
      function(lib) {
        Sys.sleep(10)
        library(package = lib, character.only = TRUE)
        return(list(search_path = search(),
                    process_id = Sys.getpid(),
                    the_time = Sys.time()))
      }
    },
    args = list(lib = lib))
    
    # wait for a result with 30 seconds timeout
    rp$wait(30000)
    if(rp$is_alive() == TRUE) {
      rp$kill()
      stop("time exceeded")
    }
    # return the result
    rp$get_result()
  }, seed = TRUE)
}
```